# How to prove the correctness of the algorithm for "Arrange given numbers to form the biggest number"?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

[Arrange given numbers to form the biggest number](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-of-numbers-arrange-the-numbers-to-form-the-biggest-number/) gives the algorithm. 
It uses the following text to prove the correctness of the algorithm:

> So how do we go about it? The idea is to use any comparison based sorting algorithm. In the used sorting algorithm, instead of using the default comparison, write a comparison function myCompare() and use it to sort numbers. Given two numbers X and Y, how should myCompare() decide which number to put first – we compare two numbers XY (Y appended at the end of X) and YX (X appended at the end of Y). If XY is larger, then X should come before Y in output, else Y should come before. For example, let X and Y be 542 and 60. To compare X and Y, we compare 54260 and 60542. Since 60542 is greater than 54260, we put Y first.

Consider three numers: `X`, `Y` and `Z`. Use `X -> Y` to indicate that `X` should come before `Y`. A comparison based algorithm can use the following two comparisons to sort `X`, `Y` and `Z` into `XYZ`: `XY >= YX` => `X -> Y` and `YZ >= ZY` => `Y -> Z`. But these two comparisons do not necessarily ensure that `XYZ` is the largest number. In other words, the fact that `X` should come before `Y` and `Y` should come before `Z` does not necessarily ensure that `XYZ` form the largest number. Take `YZX` as an example. To prove `XYZ >= YZX`, we need to prove that `X(YZ) >= (YZ)X` which meains that `X` should before `YZ` as a whole to form a bigger number.

Can anyone give a formal proof of the correctness of the algorithm?

Comment: Can you find an example of `X`, `Y` and `Z` for which the algorithm does not work correctly?

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: @BJMyers I can't. But I can't prove that such a counter example does not exist.

Comment: @Henry I have updated my question to make it clearer.

Comment: The idea behind the algorithm is to find the number X so that for any number Y in the list, XY is greater than YX; X should then be the first number, and the problem is now reduced to a list shorter by 1.

Comment: @AlexP For any number Y, the fact that XY is greater than YX means that X should come before Y. But it can't be concluded that X(a permutation of all Ys) is greater than any permutation of X and all Ys. It can't be taken as granted.

Comment: You actually need to show that for any sequences a,b,c of numbers X->Y implies aXbYc >= aYbXc

Comment: The sort fucntion is the key here. You are testing every permutation so It is valid. your are not just testing XY-YX and YZ-ZY But you are also testing for XZ-ZX. Since you are testing all permutation you are good to go.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi no, thats not true. The sort function does not necessarily do that test, it relys on the transitivity of the order function.

Comment: @Henry I don't get it. I am pretty sure that all cases will be checked.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi consider an example: 1,3,4. A sort may find 1 < 3, and 3 < 4 and conclude the array is sorted. It does not need to check 1 < 4.

Comment: @Henry Thanks I get IT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we will prove that if X "<" Y and Y "<" Z then X "<" Z. Assuming that they have p, q and r digits respectively, the first two relations reduce to

- X * 10^q + Y ≥ Y * 10^p + X ⇒ X * (10^q - 1) ≥ Y * (10^p - 1)
- Y * 10^r + Z ≥ Z * 10^q + Y ⇒ Y * (10^r - 1) ≥ Z * (10^q - 1)

We want to prove

- X * 10^r + Z ≥ Z * 10^p + X which is equivalent to X * (10^r - 1) ≥ Z * (10^p - 1)

But this can be proved simply by multiplying the first two inequalities and cancelling off common terms.

Now that we have shown that the relation is transitive (and thus can be used to define a sort order), it is easy to show that it works to solve the problem.

Suppose the numbers given are A, B, C … such that A "<" B "<" C "<" D…. We will show that A has to come first in the final number. If not, we have a string like (some prefix)XA(some suffix) as the final number. Easily, (some prefix)AX(some suffix) is a larger number because A "<" X for all X due to transitivity. Continuing in this fashion A bubbles to the left till it becomes the first element.

Now that we have fixed the first element, the same argument can be applied to B and so on to show that the best solution is ABCD…

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is only one minor case I want to add. Multiplying the first two inequalities produces X\*Y*(10^q-1)*(10^r-1) ≥ Y\*Z*(10^p-1)*(10^q-1). The common term is Y*(10^q-1). Y might be 0. If Y is 0, we have 10*X ≥ X and Z ≥ 10*Z from the first two inequalities. Z ≥ 10*Z implies Z is 0. For both X is 0 or X is nonzero, XZ ≥ ZX. So for Y=0, X "<" Z. If Y is nonzero, cancelling the common terms as you said proves that X "<" Z.